# VBA - How to Round values in Range with `With` statement

Tags: excel, vba, with-statement

Using `With` statement, how do I update `.value`s in `Range` of cells, to be the result of a Round function, which will take the individual `.value`s as a parameter.

In other words, how to write this:

```
Range("A1").Value = Round(Range("A1").Value, 0)
Range("A2").Value = Round(Range("A2").Value, 0)
```

in this form:

```
With Range("A1:A2")
    .Value = Round(.Value, 0)
End With
```

*I've seen the solution somewhere, but couldn't find it.*

Comment: `Range("A1:A2") = Round(Range("A1:A2"), 0)` will give the same error. You need to round the values of one cell at a time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function), or equivalently `VBA.Round`, does not accept an array as its first parameter.

Neither does [`WorksheetFunction.Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.round).

Use `Application.Round`, which is the late-bound form of `WorksheetFunction.Round`.

```
With Range("A1:A2")
    .Value = Application.Round(.Value, 0)
End With
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: `VBA.Round` and `WorksheetFunction.Round` do not perform the same operation. `VBA.Round` uses banker's rounding, as noted in its [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function). If you need banker's rounding, then you need to loop, but it'd be easier to do so with an array.

Comment: Just to complete this valid answer  with a side note +:) `VBA.Round()` - other than the tabular Excel form - uses so called *banker's rounding* (i.e. midpoint value 5 always rounding to the nearest even number). 
This is a standard form of rounding used in financial and statistical operations in order to minimize significant rounding errors 
over multiple rounding operations 
by consistently rounding midpoint values in a single direction. @BigBen

Comment: Excellent answer, both of you. I have some comments, but I have an urgency to deal with. I expect to come back to you later this week. Hope it's ok. Thanks

Comment: I had to catch up on rounding conversions.. It appears that VBA uses only 2 rounding conventions to handle midpoints: 1. **"Away from zero"**, e.g. 8.5 --> 9; -8.5   --> -9 (as -9 is more away from zero than -8)  and 2. **"Banker rounding"** 8.5-->8 (8 is a closer even number than 10); -8.5 --> -8.  . *Compared to other languages, such as C#/.Net, [where other conversions are available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=net-7.0)*

Comment: @simpatak - note that `Application.Round` would be from the Excel object model (and not available in say Word or Access. So "VBA uses 2 rounding conventions" is technically slightly inaccurate.

Comment: @BigBen good point. Thanks for correction. I meant VBA related to Excel